# enjoy it [as much as possible] or [to the utmost] or [immensely]

Tags: word-choice

Suppose that John has prepared some food for you. You're now eating it.  He asks you, "Why are you eating so slowly? Which of the following three replies is best?

(1) "Because I want to **enjoy it to the utmost."**

(2) "Because I want to **enjoy it as much as possible."**

(3) "Because I want to **enjoy it immensely."**

The first two versions are mine.  My non-native English speaking friends prefer version (3).  Whose version is best?

Comment: Please review *how to ask* in the Help Center.

Comment: @davidtrinh - Welcome to the community!  It's a good question (with a good answer).  I edited your question just slightly to make it a bit easier for readers to follow; I hope you don't mind the edit. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your option (1) is the best of the three on offer.

However, "savour" is a much better term to use, as it means precisely what you are looking for.

As stated at https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/savour:

> "If you savour food or drink, you eat or drink it slowly in order to
>   taste its full flavour and to enjoy it properly."

Comment: Your suggested word is great and describes precisely what I need. Somehow, the word,"savor", slipped my mind. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: @davidtrinh - Thank you for your thanks; it was my pleasure to help.

Comment: Good word -- this would be a good answer for a single-word-request question.  EWalker, I can see you have a lot to offer here, and thanks for your efforts.  As you get more experience with the site, you'll notice when a question is badly posed and will be closed, and then you will refrain from writing an answer.